# alt show combination of key but ctrl don't

Tags: java

this is my code : 
//in UIclass.java I set key listener to text area

```
jtextArea = new JTextArea(); 
jtextArea.addKeyListener(new keyEventClass());
```

//in keyEventClass

```
class keyEventClass implements KeyListener { 

public keyEventClass() {} 

public keyPressed (KeyEvent ke) {} 

public keyReleased (KeyEvent ke) {} 

public keyTypped (KeyEvent ke) { 

        charter ch = ke.getKeyChar(); 

        if(ke.isControlDown()==true) { 

            System.out.println("You Pressed : Ctrl+"+ch); 
        } 
        else if(ke.isAltDown()==true) { 

            System.out.println("You pressed : Alt+"+ch); 
        } 
        else { 

            System.out.println("You pressed : "+ch); 
        } 
} 
} 
};
```

it show output

you pressed - ctrl plus some symbol

you pressed - alt plus s

you pressed - ctrl plus smilly

you pressed - alt plus o

correct me with my code or logic or give me something like fflush like in c

Comment: I don't know what you're asking

Comment: Your post is not clear. What is your problem?

Comment: The code you've shown won't compile. The methods all lack return types. Also, 'keyTypped` is misspelled. You should probably be using [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of a `KeyListener`.

Comment: sorry, didn't copy real code I just give you the logic I used in keyTyped() method. Just copy that logical code in your KeyListener class and tell me why ctrl returning symbols in combination but alt don't

Comment: I am asking that, in combination alt get ch as real character but with ctrl ch returns some symbols why is that @Michael